# How to Get these Bracket Boxes to align property?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to modify a bracket I found online but since I added some extra labels and such the bracket alignment is off.

[image]

I have tried to play around with the padding but I can't get it aligned (not sure if there is a better way to do the alignment as this way seems very finicky as if I add anything else it will skew all the numbers of). Also the games are pretty squished together and not spaced out.

I tried to make codepen version of it and even though it is essentially the same code(just switched out the logo for a placeholder img) the space is better for whatever reason.

https://codepen.io/chobo2/full/BayERKw

```
#bracket {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.9);
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 40px 0;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.split {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 42%;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.champion {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 16%;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: -15px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 230px 0\9;
}
.champion i {
  color: #a0a6a8;
  font-size: 45px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.round {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 95%;
  width: 30.8333%\9;
}
.split-two {
}
.split-one .round {
  margin: 0 2.5% 0 0;
}
.split-two .round {
  margin: 0 0 0 2.5%;
}
.matchup {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.score {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: right;
  color: #2c7399;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
}
.logo-img{
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
.team {
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.round-two .matchup {
  margin: 0;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
.round-three .matchup {
  margin: 0;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 130px 0;
}
.round-four .matchup {
    margin: 0;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 290px 0;
}
.round-details {
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #2c7399;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
}
.champion li,
.round li {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  opacity: 0.45;
}
.current li {
  opacity: 1;
}
.current li.team {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.final {
  margin: 4.5em 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.region-header{
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;;
}
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code as a [mre] here on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make it runnable here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I tried to post all the code but it would not let me post as it was over the limit.

Comment: That's why I mentioned **minimal** reproducible example. Maybe just one game at each level or something?

Comment: Do you just need west and east or is there more headers? Given the grid being perfect as is without the new headers you added, consider adding them outside of the flex grid, if it is only east and west, then you can add them above the entire table

Comment: The basic issue is that you have these extra elements which makes the grid unaligned, if you add an empty title to each column without a title, it will help the align a little bit but far from perfect, adding the titles outside of this premade grid is the easiest solution for now

Comment: There would be 4 headers, one for each reason which (East,West,South and midwest). this is sort of an official one that I am trying to 
 model after: https://www.ncaa.com/march-madness-live/bracket . I am not sure where outside I should put them though.